# How to retrieve a specific object from serializeArray in jQuery

Tags: jquery, arrays, serialization

I am using a serializeArray() to get the form data. I want a single object data to validate and that object is an array

[image]

I need only the data from

> dps_opening_hour[0] to dps_opening_hour[6]

and

> dps_closing_hour[0] to dps_closing_hour[6]

. How can I achieve this?

```
(function($){
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#shipping-hours-form').on('click', '.update_shipping_hours_options', function(e) {
        alert("button clicked");
        var formData = $('#shipping-hours-form').serializeArray();
        $.each(formData, function(i, field){
            console.log(field.name);
            console.log(field.value);
        });

    });
});
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: what value are you getting in console log

Comment: I am getting the correct values( for example you can see 0 and 46) in console log. I just want to use these array values to validate

Comment: push the value to an array and using Array.map function to check or loop to the value to check it.